# eigenvalues lesser than 1 implies affine maps are eventually contractive

Tags: linear-algebra, numerical-methods, numerical-linear-algebra

Consider $(\mathbb R^n,d)$ where $d$ is the Euclidean metric. A map $w:\mathbb R^n\to \mathbb R^n$ is said $\textbf{contractive}$ if there exists $0<s<1$ such that for every $x,y\in \mathbb R^n$ we have $d(w(x),w(y))\le sd(x,y)$.

Similarly, a map $w:\mathbb R^n\to \mathbb R^n$ is said $\textbf {eventually contractive}$  if there exists a positive integer $N$ such that $w^N$ is contractive.

Lastly, a map $w:\mathbb R^n\to \mathbb R^n$ is an $\textbf{affine map}$ if $w(x)=Ax+b$ where $A \in \mathbb R^{n\times n}$ and $b\in \mathbb R^n$.

> Consider the affine map $f:\mathbb R^n\to \mathbb R^n$ given by $f(x)=Ax+b$. Prove that if every eigenvalue of $A$ is lesser than $1$ then $f$ is eventually contractive

My idea was to apply the well known fact that if every eigenvalue of $A$ is lesser than 1 (namely $|\lambda_i|<1$), then we have $\lim_{k\to\infty} A^k=0$. By this, I can claim that from a certain $k_0$ on, $A^{k_0}$ is "quite" similar to the matrix $0$ and so $A^{k_0}$ is contractive, but I can't formally prove it. Thank you very much.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The hypothesis implies that for each $1 >\epsilon > 0$, there exists $N_{\epsilon}$ such that $||A^{N_{\epsilon}}|| < \epsilon$.*

On iterating $f$, we get $f^{n}x = A^{n}x + \sum_{k=0}^{n-1}A^{k}b$.

$\left|\left|f^{n}(x) - f^{n}(y)\right |\right| = \left|\left|A^{n}(x) - A^{n}(y)\right|\right| = \left|\left|A^{n}(x-y)\right|\right| \leq \left|\left|A^{n}\right|\right|\cdot||x-y||$.

(*) follows from this general truth: Suppose $g(x) = \frac{1}{1-x}$, where $|x| < 1$. Then if all the eigenvalues of $A$ are less than 1 in absolute value, then $\sum_{k=0}^{\infty}A^{k}$ converges to $g(A)$ --- the usual trick of starting off with a diagonalizable case and then invoking a normal form permitted by your problem is one way of showing this fact.

Comment: If $H$ is a normed linear space of finite dimension, then all norms on $H$ are equivalent.

Comment: ok thank you. Moreover, why if the series coverges to g(A) this implies that $||A^{N_\epsilon}||<\epsilon$. Could you give me some details please?

Comment: If $\sum_{n=0}^{\infty} a_{n} < \infty$, then necessarily, $\lim_{n \to \infty} a_{n} =0$

Comment: I knew the fact about the series, but now my doubt is what $\lim_{k\to \infty} A^k=0$ means. I thought it means that every component of $A^k$ was near enough to $0$ from a certain $k$ on. Does it mean actually that the norm of $A^k$ tends to 0? thank you again

Comment: The concept of 'near' or convergence is best captured in terms of distances, lengths and norms etc. Try and write out a similar convergence of a real sequence and see that you will use the concept of distance to write out an epsilon proof. Of course, there is a way a norm of a matrix is related to the entries of a matrix. Try and assume $A$ is a diagonal matrix with diagonal entries being its eigenvalues.

Comment: ok so if we say that $\lim_{k\to \infty}A^k=B\in \mathbb R^{n\times n}$ we mean that for every $\epsilon >0$ there is $N_0$ such that for every $n>N_0$ we have $||A^n-B||<\epsilon$ right? However looking at the spectral radius theorem on wikipedia it appears that $\lim_{k\to \infty}A^k=0$ means that every entries of $A^k$ tend to $0$.

Comment: You can write that as $\lim_{k \to \infty}||A^{k}-B||_{\infty} =0$. Matrix convergence is entry-wise and so you were not wrong initially, but using norms is the best way to handle computations neatly.

Comment: sorry but if I assume that that limit of my question means that every entry tends to 0 how can I deduce that for every norm I have $||A^{N_\epsilon}||<\epsilon$ for a suitable $N_\epsilon$ ?

Comment: Please google matrix convergence. Comments are unnecessarily getting too long.